# Python: Count lines and differentiate between them

Tags: python, count

I'm using an application that gives a timed output based on how many times something is done in a minute, and I wish to manually take the output (copy paste) and have my program, and I wish to count how many times each minute it is done.

An example output is this:

```
13:48 An event happened.
13:48 Another event happened.
13:49 A new event happened.
13:49 A random event happened.
13:49 An event happened.
```

So, the program would need to understand that 2 things happened at 13:48, and 3 at 13:49. I'm not sure how the information would be stored, but I need to average them after, to determine an average of how often it happens. Sorry for being so complicated!

Comment: Do you have quick/easy access to a database?  Are you familliar with databases?

Comment: Do you mean you want to calculate each event's frequency? e.g. "An event happened." happens once a minute?

Comment: Will this log file every span more than a day? That is, could a line appear `13:38` today, and tomorrow as well, in the same log? This could change what kind of counting technique would need to be used.

Comment: The events that happen are unimportant. I'm not familiar with databases, unfortunately. It won't spam longer than a day, no.

Comment: If the events are unimportant, what sort of output do you ultimately need from the program? Would "There were 120 events between 13:00 and 14:00, or 2 events per minute" be sufficient?

Comment: 2 events per minute would be wonderful! :P
I asked the way I did to exercise my learning and thought process, hehe. But yes, that's what I am going for.

Answer (score 4):

You could just use the time as a key for a dictionary and point it to a list of event messages. The length of that value would give you the number of events, while still letting you get at the specific events themselves:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> events = defaultdict(list)
>>> with open('log.txt') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         time, message = line.strip().split(None, 1)
...         events[time].append(message)
... 
>>> pprint(dict(events)) # pprint handles defaultdicts poorly
{'13:48': ['An event happened.', 'Another event happened.'],
 '13:49': ['A new event happened.',
           'A random event happened.',
           'An event happened.']}
```

If you want to be extra fancy, you could parse the time into a time object.

**Edit:** Take into account Mike Graham's suggestions.

Comment: In modern versions of Python, using `events = collections.defaultdict(list)` instead of `dict`'s `setdefault` method provides a slightly nicer API. Also, it is good form always to use a context manager (`with open('log.txt') as f: for line in f:`) for ensuring that files get closed.

Comment: Depending on the final needs and the amount of data, it may also be sensible to simply store a count (integer) as the value instead of a list. Default to zero and increment the current key on each line.

Comment: @Answer~ How would I get it to count the number of objects in a dictionary?  And how would I count them dynamically? By that I mean, I won't know the times before hand, so I'll need to be able to count them all anyways. And eventually use the program to add them together.

@Mike~ I'm curious to learn more about this context manager you speak of, hehe. I don't understand the statement you use as an example.

@Ipsquiggle~ that's interesting, care to explain more?

Comment: You can use '''len(events['13:48'])''' to count number of events,

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a count of how many events happen each minute then you don't really need python, you can do it from bash:

```
 cut -d ' ' -f1 filename | uniq -c
```

gives

```
  2 13:48
  3 13:49
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to know what happen but only how many times then:

```
$ python3.1 -c'from collections import Counter
import fileinput
c = Counter(line.split(None, 1)[0] for line in fileinput.input() if line.strip())
print(c)' events.txt
```

Output:

```
Counter({'13:49': 3, '13:48': 2})
```

Comment: In Perl: `$ perl -lane'$h{$F[0]}++ if $F[0]; END{$,=" "; print @r while (@r = each %h)}' events.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `groupby` function from an `itertools` module with time as a grouping key.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lines = (line.strip().split(None, 1) for line in open('log.txt'))
>>> for key, group in itertools.groupby(lines, key=itemgetter(0)):
...     print '%s - %s' % (key, map(itemgetter(1), group))
... 
13:48 - ['An event happened.', 'Another event happened.']
13:49 - ['A new event happened.', 'A random event happened.', 'An event happened.']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{_[$1]++}END{for(i in _) print i,_[i]}' filename
```